# Can docker entrypoint in shell form use runtime command args?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, kubernetes

Here is a sample dockerfile with a shell-form entrypoint:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo "(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image ($0)"
```

Below, are some of the outputs that I see from various runs:

```
$ docker run -it sc-test:v4
(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image (/bin/sh)
$ docker run -it sc-test:v4 /bin/echo
(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image (/bin/echo)
$ docker run -it sc-test:v4 /bin/cat
(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image (/bin/cat)
$ docker run -it sc-test:v4 /bin/dog
(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image (/bin/dog)
$ docker run -it sc-test:v4 "/bin/dog ($0)"
(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image (/bin/dog (-bash))
```

Based on docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), we can see that the command args are ignored.

However, the value of `$0` changes with the args provided. Can someone explain why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the docs are just wrong. Arguments from `CMD` are definitely not being ignored in my test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table in that part of the Docker documentation isn't technically correct: Docker doesn't actually drop or ignore the command part when there's a shell-form entrypoint.  What actually happens here (and your example demonstrates) is:

1. If either the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` (or both) is the shell form, it's wrapped in `["/bin/sh", "-c", "..."]`.
2. The `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` lists are concatenated to form a single command list.

Let's take your third example.  This is, in Dockerfile syntax,

```
ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo "(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image ($0)"
CMD ["/bin/cat"]
```

and the resulting combined command is (in JSON array syntax, expanded for clarity)

```
[
  "/bin/sh",
  "-c",
  "/bin/echo \"(shell) ENTRYPOINT@image ($0)\"",
  "/bin/cat"
]
```

So, what does `sh -c` do if you give it multiple arguments?  The [POSIX spec for the `sh` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) documents the syntax as

```
sh -c command_string [command_name [argument...]]
```

and further documents

> **-c**: Read commands from the *command_string* operand. Set the value of special parameter 0 [...] from the value of the *command_name* operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, and so on) in sequence from the remaining *argument* operands. No commands shall be read from the standard input.

That's what you're seeing in your examples.  If `ENTRYPOINT` is a bare string and `CMD` is a JSON array, then within the `ENTRYPOINT` string command, the arguments in `CMD` can be used as `$0`, `$1`, and so on.  If both are bare strings, both get wrapped in `sh -c`, and you'll get something like:

```sh
ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo "$0 is /bin/sh, $1 is -c, and then $2"
CMD the rest of the line
```

In your first example, the command part is empty, and in this case (still from the POSIX `sh` documentation)

> If *command_name* is not specified, special parameter 0 shall be set to [...] normally a pathname used to execute the sh utility.

Your last example is slightly more subtle:

```sh
docker run -it sc-test:v4 "/bin/dog ($0)"
```

Since the string is double-quoted, your *local* shell expands the `$0` reference in it, which is how `bash` gets in there; then since it's a single (quoted) word, it becomes the single *command_name* argument to `sh -c`.

---

There's two more normal patterns for using `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together.  The pattern I prefer has `CMD` be a full shell command, and `ENTRYPOINT` does some first-time setup and then runs a command like `exec "$@"` to run that command.  There's also a "container as command" pattern where `ENTRYPOINT` has a complete command (perhaps with involved JVM arguments) and `CMD` additional options.  In these cases the `ENTRYPOINT` *must* be JSON-array syntax:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/script-that-exec-dollar-at.sh"]
CMD ["the_command", "--option"]
```

Since the `ENTRYPOINT` string doesn't *directly* reference `$0`, `$1`, *etc.* the `CMD` arguments are *effectively* ignored by the `sh -c` wrapper.  If you had `ENTRYPOINT script.sh` it would be invoked by `sh -c` as a subprocess with no arguments, and the `CMD` would get lost.

It's probably clearer for the Docker documentation to say "if `ENTRYPOINT` is a string then `CMD` is ignored" than to try to explain the subtleties of this.

Comment: (Since you tagged this with [tag:kubernetes]: in a pod spec, `command:` is the entrypoint and `args:` is the command.)